# Firebase cloud function cannot read .env variables

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I followed this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env) and added .env file with variables in a Firebase Cloud Function project.

When trying to deploy, I get this message: `Loaded environment variables from .env`.

However, it is always undefined when I try to use `process.env.ENV_VAR`. Am I missing something?

I'm using firebase-cli 11.0.1 and firebase-functions 3.21.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used env variables for firebase credentials. Seems like it was loaded before env var. So my solution is to use firebase function config